# Pass configuration to Keycloak SPI Provider?

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, keycloak-spi

I am trying to create an `EventListenerProvider` implementation in Keycloak 22.x for the purposes of listening to user account creation events.  I've written the provider code itself and it is working without issue.  Now I am trying to allow for the configuration to be externalized rather than hard-coded in the code and I am running into issues.

My `EventListenerProviderFactory` implementation is rather simple and looks like this:

```
public class MyEventListenerProviderFactory implements EventListenerProviderFactory {

 ...snip...

 public String getId() {
   return "myAppEventListener";
 }

 public void init(Scope config) {
   ...snip...
 }

 public EventListenerProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
   return new MyEventListenerProvider();
 }

 ...snip...

}
```

As I understand from [the documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration-provider), I should be able to provide my configuration parameters on the command line using the SPI ID.  In my case, I should be able to specify a parameter that looks like:

```
spi-my-app-event-listener-myproperty=mypropertyvalue
```

That should result in me being able to do the following in the `init(Scope config)` method:

```
public void init(Scope config) {
  String myPropertyValue = config.get("myproperty");
  System.out.println("myPropertyValue=" + myPropertyValue);
}
```

However, I always get a `null` value for this property.  I am using `docker-compose` and the [official Docker container](https://quay.io/organization/keycloak) to launch Keycloak, and am setting the property value in the `command` stanza like this:

```
  command: start-dev --spi-my-app-event-listener-myproperty=mypropvalue --import-realm
```

I *thought* that this would correctly set the property, but it looks like I may be wrong about that.  Any idea where my issue lies and why I am unable to set a configuration value and read it in my event listener provider factory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the documentation describes the format as:

```
spi-<spi-id>-<provider-id>-<property>=<value>
```

which means you'd need:

```
spi-events-listener-my-app-event-listener-myproperty=mypropvalue
```

If you look at the source, you'll see that EventListenerProviderFactory's SPI is "eventsListener".

There are a few elements to an SPI:

1. The SPI itself
2. Factory
3. Provider
4. Metadata

Comment: That did it.  Interestingly, calling config.getPropertyNames() returns an empty array, but if I call config.get("myProperty") I get the correct value.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Great! Looking at the source for the config class, there's only one implementation that does anything (all the others throw NotImplemented), but it's not immediately obvious why it's giving you an empty array.